# Node module deleted from npm during autoscaling trigger. How to handle this?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, autoscaling

I am using AWS autoscaling via Elasticbeanstalk.

I have uploaded my node app on S3 & have mentioned all required modules to be installed during setup in package.json

When an autoscale trigger initiates new instance, it will download app from S3 & start installing modules mentioned in package.json

What if during this time some modules were already deleted from npm & my package.json were referring to them. In that case my instance won't start correctly & my autoscale purpose will be nullified.

**How can I ensure that during each autoscale node modules are already available to the app?**

I thought of making custom AMI in which all my modules are globally installed. So during autoscale my app can directly reference them. But during update if I had used additional modules then how will existing instances install them during deploying app on them.

Please suggest better way to handle this scenario

Answer (score 1):

You should install your dependencies when you release a new version of your app. i.e. You should install your dependencies into S3 with your app, so that autoscaling isn't dependent on NPM.

I'm not sure if ElasticBeanstalk supports this, but you can probably just put your dependencies into the node_modules subdirectory in your source bundle so that they're available to the app locally and don't need installing if it autoscales.

Comment: even i thought so...all packages might be of approx 50MB so deployment time will need to be taken into consideration in autoscale config isnt it...thanks for ur answer